# WebBrowser DocumentCompleted with Ajax Calls

Tags: c#, ajax, browser

I have a webbrowser control in my C-Sharp application. Everything works fine.
I am stuck on a file upload control.

I could manage to get that working as well.

However, when I choose a file from file upload control , an ajax call is performed and the file is uploaded to the server. The image thumbnail is shown on the page.

This all works fine when I have a slow internet connection and pages load slowly.

However with a faster connection, DOcumentCompleted event is fired even before these images are uploaded and therefore, the images are lost.

Please let me know how can I make the browser wait for those to upload.

PS - I have tried using timers, but that does not work either.

Thanks
Ashutosh

Comment: If you use Webbrowser control only to upload images, you have better alternatives like HttpWebRequest, WebClient or HttpClient...

Comment: You'll have to make the file upload a synchronous part of your page load; in other words, don't allow the page to complete loading until the file has completed uploading.  Hook into the OnUploadComplete event (or equivalent) of the file uploader to check.

Comment: @L.B - I can not use WebClient etc since its not a regular update process however its actually like I am uploading a file from the machine to the website.

Comment: @brinky this is not a file uploader control but an input type=file.